# Is malloc needed in iOS to define a dynamically sized array

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, dynamic-arrays, calloc

For performance reasons I had to write some of my code in C instead of Objective-C. Coding faster than I think, I defined an array whose size can be determined only in run time:

```
int myArray[requestedSize];
```

I got no complaints from Xcode or when I compiled. Is Objective-C allocating memory giving above statement?

To be safe I ended up using calloc

```
int* myArray = calloc(sizeof(int), requestedSize);
NSAssert(myArray != NULL,
         @"Could not allocate memory of %d ints for myArray",
         requestedSize);
```

but I am not sure if this is needed.

Comment: In C, that is *likely* supported (though not necessarily a grand idea). It declares an automatic VLA (variable length array), and nearly all modern C implementations provide it (the standard allows them not to). You're using clang and it does support it in C99 and C11 mode. Worth googling. It is *not* dynamic in the sense you may think of (heap managed). It is automatic, and as such is gone as soon as current scope is exited.

Comment: I know that gdb supported the first kind of initialisation, but some other compilers complained.